# why i am getting error while using audioplayers: ^0.17.3 package, error is "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest', Build failed"

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, avaudioplayer

I'm making app in which pressing a button plays assets audio file, earlier it was working without any problem but now i don't know what happend to my app, whenever i run app on my phisical android device, it generates error, then i update package's version number from ^0.17.0 to ^0.17.3 in pubspec.yaml but even then problem is same, but if i remove audioplayer package line from pubspec.yaml then app runs well, what happen to app please check, also check my AndroidManifest.xml file code given blow after error. thanks

**Package link:**
https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

**Following error comes whenever i run:**

```html
Launching lib\main.dart on SM M307F in debug mode...
 lib\main.dart
C:\Users\Anil\AndroidStudioProjects\newlightbulb\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] C:\Users\Anil\AndroidStudioProjects\newlightbulb\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] C:\Users\Anil\AndroidStudioProjects\newlightbulb\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**Code in AndroidManifes.xml file:**

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newflash">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="newflash"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] C:\Users\Anil\AndroidStudioProjects\newlightbulb\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audioplayer version 0.17.0 have sdk compatibility issues

Just downgrade to audioplayers: ^0.16.1

Answer (score 2):

Try using audioplayers: ^0.10.0

Comment: thanks Aniket this solved my problem but i don't know why it was working fine when i was using 0.17.0 version earlier.